# SQL Server DataLength issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, datalength

I have a column with the following data: SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH. When doing a `SELECT DATALENGTH` from the table, I am getting a value of 72.

However when I copy the column data and pop it in the select statement like the below, I get a length of 36.

```
SELECT DATALENGTH('JUDITH KOSGEY JUDITH JEPKORIR KOSGEY')
```

What could be the possible reasoning for this? I do no see any extra spaces or special characters in this text.

Comment: What do you get if you do `CONVERT(varbinary(150),YourColumn)`?

Comment: @Larnu 0x4A005500440049005400480020004B004F00530047004500590020004A005500440049005400480020004A00450050004B004F0052004900520020004B004F005300470045005900

Comment: I get 72 with `SELECT DATALENGTH(N'JUDITH KOSGEY JUDITH JEPKORIR KOSGEY');`. Note the Unicode constant prefix so it seems the column is `nvarchar`.

Comment: Well that isn't `'SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH'`.... It's `N'JUDITH KOSGEY JUDITH JEPKORIR KOSGEY'`... Even if it were `'JUDITH KOSGEY JUDITH JEPKORIR KOSGEY'` that would return a `DATALENGTH` of `36` *not* `29`...

Comment: @Larnu I've edited my question. I see I copied the incorrect value. It should be JUDITH KOSGEY JUDITH JEPKORIR KOSGEY

Comment: Your value is an `nvarchar`, not a `varchar`, @John , so you aren't actually comparing apples to apples. To get the correct `DATALENGTH` value for the literal you need to also use an `nvarchar` (as [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) shows in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74718350/sql-server-datalength-issues#comment131873622_74718350)).

Answer (score 1):

If your column is `NVARCHAR`, it is intended to handle double byte character sets.

Use `LEN(<column>)` instead of `DATALENGTH(<column>)` and you will get the value you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the data column is UNICODE which takes more storage per character.  What's the type of the column?

Comment: This alone wouldn't be enough, `N'SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH SMITH'` would have a `DATALENGTH` of `58`.